# How to install WiFi driver?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I have a fairly new Gateway Tower. I couldn't play most games on it in Windows 7 so I suspected a glitch in the OS and installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

My WiFi still works on Windows, as that is what I'm using to access the internet to ask this. But my Ubuntu doesn't bring up a wireless option in networks and when I try to install the driver from the disk, it can't read the linux version and there's an error when I try autorun. There is also a Windows version of the Driver on the disc which I tried running but it doesn't run.

I only downloaded Ubuntu about two hours ago and have never used any form of linux aside from my Android phone, so it's probably an easy problem but I have no clue how to get my internet working.

How to install the WiFi driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the web for a windows version of the driver for me. If you can find one, just tell me here. I may be able to help you wrap it. There may be better ways to do it, but this will at least get you up and running.

Comment: There is a Windows version of the Driver on the install disc.